# Get the most recent data from database to jsp page

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to get data from the last 5 days from mysql database using servlet and jsp. I created a database class where it looks for the date between the last 5 days until the current date. Then on my serlvet, I called that method and store the values in a list and forward it the jsp page. I created a table in the jsp page to display the database data, but nothing is showing up. I debugged it and it was showing the list was empty. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

Database method:

```
public static List getMaxRecordsHomePage(int id) {
    List recordList = new ArrayList<>();

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Date date = new Date();
    String currentDate = dateFormat.format(date);

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -5);
    Date previousDate = cal.getTime();
    String fromDate = dateFormat.format(previousDate);

    try {
        Connection conn = DBConnection.getConnection();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM record WHERE userId=? AND date BETWEEN ? AND ?";
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setInt(1, id);
        stmt.setString(2, fromDate);
        stmt.setString(3, currentDate);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()) {
            Record records = new Record();
            records.setId(id);
            records.setCategory(rs.getString("category"));
            records.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
            records.setAmount(rs.getString("amount"));
            records.setDate(rs.getString("date"));
            recordList.add(records);
        }   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return recordList;
    }
}
```

Serlvet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
{
    int id = SessionService.getSessionId(request, response);                    
    List recordList = FinanceService.getMaxRecordsHomePage(id);
    request.setAttribute("recordList", recordList);

    RouteService.routeDispatcher(request, response, "homepage.jsp");
}
```

JSP page:

```
<table>
    <caption>Recent Records</caption>
    <tr>
        <td>Category</td>
        <td>Short Description</td>
        <td>Amount</td>
        <td>Date</td>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="Records" items="${recordList}">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${Records.category}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${Records.description}"/></td>
            <td>$<c:out value="${Records.amount}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${Records.date}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you check your server logs. Usually it tells you some more information. I am suspecting you have a null somewhere.

Comment: @otc Yea I checked my server log but there is no error messages

Comment: in that case most likely there is no data coming back from the query. do you have an oracle or mysql database. I usually do a setDate on my statements and not set string.

Comment: also another thing you want to check is to add a logger statement or a print line with your collection size right after you have exit the while loop.

Comment: nASIM Ahmed bhai, run that sql query without any date. First run **SELECT * FROM record** and see if you get anything in return. Then proceed from there

Comment: Maybe, there is no record when userid = 1 and given that date range

Comment: When I run SELECT * FROM record where userId=?; I get all the data from mysql database. Once I add the dates, no data is showing. I also added new data to the database with todays date so atleast it should show today's data.

Comment: try this **select * from *table_name* where *datetime_column* >= '01/01/2009' and *datetime_column* <= curdate()**

Comment: and the dates you are providing should be in sql. make yours like this: **SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
java.util.Date startDate = formatter.parse(sdate);** and then when you set dates with preparedstatements, use this: **stmt.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(startDate.getTime()))**

Comment: what is the name of the date column in the table?

Comment: It is called date

Comment: okay. Did you try to give sql dates instead of util dates?

Comment: I tried your code and works well.  What is your the date type in database?  It should be 'date' or 'datetime'.

Comment: It works now, Thanks @GurkanYesilyurt and everyone else for you help, I just had to change the data type to date instead of varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The BETWEEN operator selects values within a range. The values can be numbers, text, or dates.

If you want to get date within a range, you can choose the column type as 'data', 'datetime' etc. in database.